How to run the Win32_ScheduledJob, Create function in C#?
I want to create a C# function that connects to a given computer using WMI (CimSession), and schedule a given task at a given time. I decided to use the Win32_ScheduledJob class.
public static string Create_ScheduleTask(string path, string computer, string fqdn)
{
        using var session = CimSession.Create(fqdn, DComOptions);
        if (!session.TestConnection())
            return $"{computer} - Failed to establish a connection to the computer.\n";
        
        const string className = "Win32_ScheduledJob";
        const string methodName = "Create";
        var time = new DateTime(2024, 6, 7, 12, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        
        try
        {
            var methodParameters = new CimMethodParametersCollection
            {
                CimMethodParameter.Create("Command", path, CimType.String, CimFlags.In),
                CimMethodParameter.Create("StartTime", time, CimType.DateTime, CimFlags.In)
            };
            
            var result = session.InvokeMethod(WindowsNamespace, className, methodName, methodParameters);
            if (result is not { ReturnValue: not null }) return $"{computer} - An unexpected error occurred. \n";
            
            return (uint)result.ReturnValue.Value == 0
                ? $"{computer} - Scheduled task created successfully. \n"
                : $"{computer} - Failed to create scheduled task. {result.ReturnValue.Value}\n";

        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            Err.LogExceptionError(e);
            return $"{computer} - Error executing script. {e.Message} \n";
        }
}

This the code I am running but I am getting an exit code of 8. Which according to Microsoft, Unknown failure 8 Interactive process. I don't know where in my code I could of gone wrong.
